# What is the equivalent of "npm install <package_name> --save" in Yarn?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I am using [Yarn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn) to install the dependencies of my project. What is the equivalent of "npm install <package_name> --save " in Yarn to update the entry in my `package.json` file? I can use "npm install <package_name> --save " here, but I want to use Yarn as much as possible to improve performance and avoid confusion between npm and Yarn.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

The yarn equivalent to`npm install <name> --save` is:

```
yarn add <name>
```

[Here's the link to the docs](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/migrating-from-npm#toc-cli-commands-comparison) for the full list of commands in comparison to `npm`.

Comment: Notice that the documentation (erroneously) states that NPM counterpart is `npm install [package]`, while it's `npm install --save [package]` in fact.

Comment: @estus the `--save` flag is not required anymore when using npm. If you don't want npm to save we now have to use `npm --no-save` :)

Comment: Thanks for reminding. I have `save` option disabled globally in order for NPM to be consistent between versions.

Comment: `yarn add` does not appear to update package.json by default

Comment: @toastyghost I've just migrated from Yarn 1.x to 3.x and never esperienced a package not being added/removed from pakage.json using `yarn add|remove` I'm recommending the use of LTS versions. Try deleting `node_modules` and clean the cache then reinstall, there might be another issue regarding to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48654681/yarn-add-does-not-install-dependencies

Answer (score 121):

Use the following command :

```
yarn add [package_name]
```

### Comparing npm and Yarn Commands

**Install dependencies**

```
npm install => yarn
```

**Install a package**

```
npm install [package_name] => yarn add [package_name]
```

**Install a package globally**

```
npm install -g [package_name] => yarn global add [package_name]
```

**Install a package as a development dependency**

```
npm install --save-dev [package_name] => yarn add --dev [package_name]
```

**Uninstall a package**

```
npm uninstall [package_name] => yarn remove [package_name]
```

**Uninstall a package globally**

```
npm uninstall -g [package_name] => yarn global remove [package_name]
```

**Uninstall a development dependency package**

```
npm uninstall --save-dev [package_name] => yarn remove [package_name]
```

**Update the dependencies**

```
npm update => yarn upgrade
```

**Update a package**

```
npm update [package_name] => yarn upgrade [package_name]
```

**Create a new package**

```
npm init => yarn init
```

**Run a script defined in the package.json**

```
npm run => yarn run
```

**Test a package**

```
npm test => yarn test
```

**Publish a package**

```
npm publish => yarn publish
```

**Remove all data from the cache**

```
npm cache clean => yarn cache clean
```

Comment: Thanks for this cheat sheet. I keep referring to this comment whenever I need :)

Comment: Very helpful. Although I never will understand why they decided to change these commands.

Answer (score 55):

Using --dev or -D will install one or more packages in your devDependencies.

```
yarn add <package...> [--dev/-D]
```

[Yarn add documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add)