# Yarn add does not install dependencies

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I am using the latest version of stable `yarn 1.3.2`. Everytime I run `yarn add <package>` it adds it to my `package.json`and `yarn.lock` but the `node_modules` does not get installed.

I have tried `yarn install --force` and still no result. The only way to get it to work is to delete my `node_modules` folder and run `yarn install`. This is annoying to do for every package I add mid project.

Has anyone faced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

uninstalled angular/cli and reinstalled.. it is now working fine

Comment: Nice. Additionally you could run `npm cache verify` first.